# How to add annotation/bookmark to video in WPF using C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I've developed an application where the user can import videos and edit them like clipping and screenshots. 

Now I want to implement the annotation/bookmarking part where user can bookmark the part of videos and add notes to it.

Here is a screenshot of the application:

[image]

I have buttons on the right where user can click and add the bookmark for some `Event 1` and bookmark will start from the current point till the user again clicks the same button.

I've no clue where to start from.

Any sort of help would be appreciated.

Comment: I've solved this problem but I'm unable to answer my question

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you already have a clue on where to start from, it's right there in your question, you just need to chop it up into smaller chunks:

> user can click and add the bookmark for some Event 1 and bookmark will start from the current point till the user again clicks the same button.

Based on this alone, what you need to be able to do is:

- store the current position in the media (from which the media will be played) for the user
- restore playback from the stored point
- implement this behavior to happen when clicking the button (either in codebehind or through some viewmodel) - to ellicit different behavior on first and second click is trivial.

I'd recommend reading through [this MS overview of media elements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/multimedia-overview?view=netframework-4.8), that will give you the background you need to do all that (control the playback).

**Edit**:
And then it's only a small step from 'stored position' to 'stored position with annotation'. How about a class that stores what you need to control the playback and a string with some text content? You could then template this into a control with a text field that would allow the user to specify his annotation. The control(s) could also contain the actual buttons to jump to the annotated point in time in the media and the buttons on the right side of your app could be reduced to one button to 'create new annotation'.

Comment: Where do store it, the event start & end time. There will be multiple events and if user imports the same video again he must see those bookmarks, I don't want those bookmarks to be limited one time. They must be accessible any time

Comment: Well, then you are looking to somehow serialize that data when it's created and deserialize it when the app opens the same media element. Key word is serialization - read this guide by MS to give you an idea: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/serialization/](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/serialization/).